# How to find the Taylor series of $ \frac{3+(x-1)^2}{6-5x} $ at $x_0=1$ and find its radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

$$ \frac{3+(x-1)^2}{6-5x}$$
I want to find the Taylor expansion of it at $x_0=1$

I'm not sure know how to do this, the only thing that I can do is to let $x-1=t$, and hence it can be simplified as $$ \frac{3+t^2}{1-5t}$$
and then find the Taylor expansion of it at $x_0=0$

Then my attempt is to directly expand the $\frac{1}{1-5t}$ to be
$$ 1+5t+(5t)^2+\cdots+(5t)^n$$

Then I multiply this polynomial by $3+t^2$ to get
$$ 3+t^2+(3+t^2)(5t)+\cdots+(3+t^2)(5t)^n$$

Then I convert $t = x-1 $ back

Is this the right way to deal with this?

If this is right, how should I find the radius of convergence of this series?. Do I need to convert it into form as $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$$ or only look at the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-5t}$ is enough?

How should I convert this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is the right way.  Once you have the first few terms of this, is there a way to check your answer (for at least those few terms)?

Comment: Also, If I want to find the radius of convergence of this Taylor series. Is it enough to only check the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-5t}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another variant, set $f(t)=\dfrac{3+t^2}{1-5t}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n\ $ and identify the coefficients for $$(1-5t)f(t)=3+t^2$$

$\begin{align}(1-5t)f(t)
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n-5\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^{n+1}\\
&=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nt^n-5\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}t^n\\
&=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-5a_{n-1})t^n\quad=\quad3+t^2\end{align}$

You get to solve the system $\begin{cases}a_0=3\\a_1-5a_0=0\\a_2-5a_1=1\\a_n-5a_{n-1}=0\quad\forall n\ge 3\end{cases}\iff
\begin{cases}a_0=3\\a_1=15\\a_2=76\\a_n=76\times5^{n-2}\quad\forall n\ge 3\end{cases}$

From $a_n=O(5^n)$ the radius of convergence of the series is $\frac 15$ which was expected since there is $1-5t$ on the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

We just recognize how to combine terms in the geometric expansion:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3+t^2}{1-5t} &= 3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(5t)^k + t^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(5t)^k \\
&= 3 + 15t + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (3\cdot5^{k}+5^{k-2})t^k
\end{align*}